# position child above parent

Tags: html, css

i have the following template:

```
<div class="messages">
  <ul class='messages__list'> // display: flex ******EDIT****** flex-direction: column
    <li *ngFor="let msg of currConversation.messages" class="messages__list__item">
      <span class="message-full-date">date</span> // position: fixed, left: 45%;
      <p class="message message-name">name</p>
      <p class="message message-content">content</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

i want to position the span (full-date) in a "row" above the "li" - so they won't be positioned on top of each other on small screens. is there a way to do it?

i tried to position the other elements in a different way (absolute, relative, fixed), and to display them differently but it didn't work for me.

i also tried to use the css "::after"/"::before' and also failed..

Comment: set span parent to position:relative and span to absolute;bottom:100%; .See if that's okay to start with

Comment: yea its a start, but the span is getting on top of its sibilling

Comment: you might need to add a margin-top to the parent, of about the height the span. it should help a bit

Comment: that's great! now if you know how to position it in the center of the grandparent (the ul/div) it will be awesome. i tried 'left'/'right' and it didnt work

Comment: is there a way to implement it even if the span is conditionally and does not exist in every ```li```?

Comment: to handle this via css, you might use a pseudo and a data attribute . i've made an answer to show the idea .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ould relay on position relative/absolute to use the parent as a reference.

example :

```css
.messages__list__item {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 1.2em;
}

.message-full-date {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: max-content;
  margin: auto;
}
.flex {display:flex;}
.flex li {flex:1}

/* see us */
li , .message-full-date{border:solid 1px;}
```

```html
<div class="messages">
  <ul class='messages__list'>
    <li *ngFor="let msg of currConversation.messages" class="messages__list__item">
      <span class="message-full-date">date</span>
      <p class="message message-name">name</p>
      <p class="message message-content">content</p>
    </li>
    <li *ngFor="let msg of currConversation.messages" class="messages__list__item">
      <span class="message-full-date">date</span>
      <p class="message message-name">name</p>
      <p class="message message-content">content</p>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>

<div class="messages">
  <ul class='messages__list flex '>
    <li *ngFor="let msg of currConversation.messages" class="messages__list__item">
      <span class="message-full-date">date</span>
      <p class="message message-name">name</p>
      <p class="message message-content">content</p>
    </li>
    <li *ngFor="let msg of currConversation.messages" class="messages__list__item">
      <span class="message-full-date">date</span>
      <p class="message message-name">name</p>
      <p class="message message-content">content</p>
    </li>
    <li *ngFor="let msg of currConversation.messages" class="messages__list__item">
      <span class="message-full-date">date</span>
      <p class="message message-name">name</p>
      <p class="message message-content">content</p>
    </li>
    <li *ngFor="let msg of currConversation.messages" class="messages__list__item">
      <span class="message-full-date">date</span>
      <p class="message message-name">name</p>
      <p class="message message-content">content</p>
    </li>
    <li *ngFor="let msg of currConversation.messages" class="messages__list__item">
      <span class="message-full-date">date</span>
      <p class="message message-name">name</p>
      <p class="message message-content">content</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

you could also use the ::before pseudo to generate this container if a date has to be shown

```css
li.message-full-date:not([data-date=""]) {
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;/* possibly useful */
}
.flex li.message-full-date:not([data-date=""]) {
  margin: 0 0 0 2px ;/* possibly useful */
}

.message-full-date:not([data-date=""])::before {
  content: 'date :'attr(data-date);
  display: block;
  width: max-content;
  margin: auto;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex li {
  flex: 1
}


/* see us */

li,
.message-full-date::before {
  border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="messages">
  <ul class='messages__list'>
    <li *ngFor="let msg of currConversation.messages" class="messages__list__item  message-full-date" data-date="01/01/01">
      <p class="message message-name">name</p>
      <p class="message message-content">content</p>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>

<div class="messages">
  <ul class='messages__list flex'>
    <li *ngFor="let msg of currConversation.messages" class="messages__list__item  message-full-date" data-date="01/01/01">
      <p class="message message-name">name</p>
      <p class="message message-content">content</p>
    </li>
    <li *ngFor="let msg of currConversation.messages" class="messages__list__item  message-full-date" data-date="">
      <p class="message message-name">name</p>
      <p class="message message-content">content</p>
    </li>
    <li *ngFor="let msg of currConversation.messages" class="messages__list__item  message-full-date" data-date="01/02/01">
      <p class="message message-name">name</p>
      <p class="message message-content">content</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: great! i used the ```data``` attribute binding. however i still can't position the date in the center of the div. i forgot to mention that the ```ul``` parent is flex-direction: column